# how to use bitsharp library to get transaction from you wallet

Tags: bitsharp

I am doing some test with bitcoins. I download BitCoin-qt and create my wallet and my address for sending receiving bitcoin.

I am now trying to read the wallet I've created to send an email when a new payment is received.

I have come to the BitSharp library, but unfortunately I do not understand very much how to use it.

I mean as far as I have understood you could use a test network for your test but when I try to link to my wallet.dat file I get an error from the code and I cannot understand why.

My problem is that I need to understand how to code a software like this.

I have a wallet correctly set up I can see transactions send and receive. 
How should I connect to it to see with and eventlistener if new transactions arrived in my wallet so to generate an alert?

Thanks in advance for the help

Paolo

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to access wallet.dat file for this. Bitcoin-qt has some methods for this kind of events.

You need to change your bitcoin.conf file.

```
walletnotify=c:\walletnotify.bat %s
blocknotify=c:\blocknotify.bat %s
```

This methods calling when new transfer in your wallet or when new block has been found.